# When is a power series with coefficients in {0,1} algebraic?

Tags: co.combinatorics

If we have a series $F(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ where $a_n$ is in {0,1} for every integer $n$. Is $F$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ (set of rational numbers). If it is, under what conditions?
Thank you.

Comment: I take the question to be, under what conditions on the sequence will the (formal) series be an algebraic function. 

Comment: I tried to improve the title...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a classical rational-transcendental dichotomy for power series with coefficients which don't grow too fast. Here are two famous results:

> P. Fatou, "Series trigonometriques et series de Taylor", Acta Math. (1906), no. 30, 335–400.

Fatou proves that if a power series $F(x)\in \mathbb Z[[x]]$ converges inside the unit disk, then either $F(x)\in \mathbb Q(x)$ or $F(x)$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q(x)$.

> F. Carlson, "Uber Potenzreihen mit ganzzahligen Koeﬃzienten.", Math. Zeitschr. (1921), no. 9, 1–13.

Carlson proves that if $F(x)\in \mathbb Z[[x]]$ converges inside the unit disk, then either $F(x)$ is rational or $F(x)$ admits the unit circle as a natural boundary.

This tells you that your series if it is algebraic then it must be a rational function with rational coefficients. This happens if and only if the binary number $0.a_1a_2\dots$ is eventually periodic (to see this just plug in $x= \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: You could wonder why this "corresponding" question is much harder: if a **number** $a \in (0,1)$ has only $0,1$ in its decimal expansion, then either it is rational or transcendental.  That is surely true, but there is no known proof.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar "if a number a∈(0,1) has only 0,1 in its decimal expansion, then either it is rational or transcendental" is implied from"Carlson proves that if F(x)∈Z[[x]] converges inside the unit disk, then either F(x) is rational or F(x) admits the unit circle as a natural boundary.", right? Since, power series with natural boundary is transcendental function, Is it necessary to give a proof?

Comment: @XL_at_China ... I don't see how Carlson's result about a function can be applied to my question about a number.  (But of course if we can find out how to do this, we will be famous.)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Good morning,Gerald. what do you think about a power series with natural boundary? Could it be non-transcendental (which means rational or algebraic)? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: My comment was about a number $a$.  Not a function.  So what is the connection with Carlson's theorem about a function?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar okay, I see. I think we could try to find the how and be famous.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to [Asymptotics/growth for coefficients of algebraic power series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72677/asymptotics-growth-for-coefficients-of-algebraic-power-series) will be helpful.