# Any closed form for series like $F(x)=\sum\limits_{p=2}^{\infty}x^p,$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, closed-form-expressions

Any closed form for series like $$F(x)=\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}x^p,\quad p\text{ is prime}$$ or $$F(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i!}\quad ?$$

More generally, we can obtain a power series from decimal expansion of a number $r$ (with $0< r<1$) by replacing $$\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^i$$ with $$x^i$$ like $$\frac{1}{3}=3\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^1+3\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2+\dotsb 3\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^i+\dotsb.$$
In this example we obtain:
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}3x^i.$$

- When $f(x)$  is convergent, what restriction do we have to  put on $r$ (if $r$ is c.e. number) to make $f(x)$ have a closed form?
- When is $f(x)$  algebraic, or transcendental?

Comment: Your first display makes no sense. Maybe you meant $$\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}x^p,p{\rm\ is\ prime}$$

Comment: This might be better expression: $$\sum_{p\textrm{ prime}} x^p$$

Comment: XL, you came back here to edit your question, but did nothing to engage with the comments. Why?

Comment: @Gerry,@i707i707,thank both of you very much,your expressions are right,they are what I intend to express

Comment: Here is an answered related question https://mathoverflow.net/q/80572/22277. Here we find out F. Carlson has shown in 1921 that power series with integer coefficients and radius of convergence 1 are either rational or have the unit disk as a natural boundary.

Comment: @JosephVanName， excellent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this blog post: https://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com/tag/power-series/

which contains a proof of the result by Fatou:

A function whose power series expansion has integer coefficients and radius of convergence 1 is either rational (in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$) or transcendental (over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$).

If $r$ is rational, then the decimal expansion will be eventually periodic. So we have rational function. (Indeed this can be done explicitly)

Otherwise, when $r$ is irrational, then the resulting function cannot be rational (plug in $1/10$, then you get irrational number). Thus, we have transcendence of $f$.

In particular, your functions $F$ in the beginning are transcendental.
However, getting closed form will be extremely hard for those examples.

Comment: @i707i707,thank you.But it is only a partial answer to this question,especially,when r is algebraic number

Comment: XL, if the answer is helpful, even if it's not a complete answer, I'd encourage you to vote it up. 

Comment: @Gerry,thank you for your reminding

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, $r$ can be either rational or irrational. When $r$ is rational, the function $f$ is rational, and when $r$ is irrational, the function $f$ is transcendental. 

Comment: @i707107,those hold ,provided a series is convergent with radius r,otherwise,they may not hold,am I right?For instance,$$f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x^2}$$

Comment: Hold for series convergent with radius 1. Any series obtained from your setting, will have radius of convergence 1, or infinity. 
The case when radius of convergence infinity, is only when $r$ has finite decimal expansion. 

Comment: Maybe you wanted to link to this post: [Uniformly at Random](https://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/power-series-with-integer-coefficients/) (rather than to list of all posts tagged power-series)? (Of course, since there are only two such posts, anybody can easily find that link.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for [that](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1104170) link; I tried to [guess](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/131678/4) and got it [wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/131678/5), because I didn't notice there were two posts.  Tiny correction:  [Uniformly at Random](https://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com) is the name of the blog, whereas [Power series with integer coefficients](https://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/power-series-with-integer-coefficients)

Answer (score 11):

Also, the classical [Fabry gap theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fabry_theorem) tells you that the unit circumference is the natural boundary. Meanwhile, all "elementary" functions can be analytically continued along almost every path on the plane, so give up all hopes for a closed formula of any sort...

Comment: @fedja,thank you,only can one post be chosen as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Functions with a natural boundary tend to satisfy functional equations, and they are sometimes the unique solutions to those functional equations. While a system of functional equations is far from being a closed form expression, systems of functional equations are probably as close as we can get to closed form expressions for these kinds of otherwise pathological functions.

The following observations apply to the function $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{k!}$ and related functions.

Observation: Suppose that $f$ is a function holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ with $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k z^{k}$. Let $m/n$ be a reduced rational number. The following are equivalent:

1. $f(z\cdot e^{2\pi im/n})-f(z)$ is a polynomial.
2. For all but finitely many $k$, $a_k=0$ or $k$ is a multiple of $n$ .
3. There is some $k$ where $f$ satisfies the functional differential equation
   $$\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\big(f(z\cdot e^{2\pi im/n})-f(z)\big)=0.$$

Observation: Suppose that $f(z)$ is a function that is analytic in a neighborhood of $z=0$. Let $(r_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers where $r_n$ is always a factor of $r_{n+1}$. Then $f(z)$ can be put in the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^{r_k}$ if and only if $f^{(r)}(0)=0$ for $r<r_0$ and for all $n\geq 0$, $f(z)$ satisfies the functional differential equation $$\frac{d^{r_{n+1}}}{dz^{r_{n+1}}}\big(f(z)-f(z\cdot\exp(2\pi i/r_{n+1}))\big)=0.$$
Suppose now that $f$ satisfies these conditions. Then
$$\frac{d^{r_n}}{dz^{r_n}}\big(f(z)-f(z\cdot\exp(2\pi i/r_{n+1}))\big)=a_n\cdot (r_n)!\cdot\big(1-\exp(\frac{2\pi i r_n}{r_{n+1}})\big)$$ for each $n\geq 0$, and the function $f(z)$ is completely determined by these functional differential equations.